# if dentro de un return (java)

Tags: java, array, condiciones

obtengo un valor con set y get, ese valor al imprimir el arreglo, quiero primero evaluar si el precio es menor a 150,000, si es asi, que lo multiplique por el iva1 1.16, si es mayor a 150,000 que lo multiplique por iva2 1.20, pero sin importar el precio siempre multiplica por 1.16, es decir, si capturo 160,000 en el precio igual me lo multiplica por 1.16

```
public float getprecio(){
        return this.precio;
    }

    //con override forzamos al compilador a comprobar en la compilación que estamos sobrescribiendo un método
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        float iva1=(float) 1.16;
        float iva2=(float) 1.20;

        if (15000 < precio) {
            return
                    ("Marca:"+
                    this.marca+" "+
                    "Modelo:"+
                    this.modelo+" "+
                    "Uso:"+
                    this.uso+" "+
                    "Año:"+
                    this.año+" "+
                    "Precio:$"+
                    iva1*this.precio
                    );
        } else {
            return
                    ("Marca:"+
                    this.marca+" "+
                    "Modelo:"+
                    this.modelo+" "+
                    "Uso:"+
                    this.uso+" "+
                    "Año:"+
                    this.año+" "+
                    "Precio:$"+
                    iva2*this.precio
                    );
        }
```

Edito:
La variable la declaro desde el inicio de la clase

public class Auto {

```
//declaramos los tipos de datos de cada variable
// tipo cadena para los datos largos
//tipo numerico para los que correspondan
private String marca="";
private String modelo="";
private String uso="";
private int año=0;
private float precio=0;

public Auto(){
    // Empty constructor
}

public Auto(String marca, 
            String modelo,
            String uso,
            int año,
            float precio){
    this.marca=marca;
    this.modelo=modelo;
    this.uso=uso;
    this.año=año;
    this.precio=precio;
}
```

Comment: una pregunta ¿precio es una variable mienbro?, sino es el caso, tienes que pasarsela como parametro al metodo

Comment: la variable la declaro desde el inicio de la clase

Comment: en el if pusiste 15.000 en lugar de 150.000

Comment: jejeje, ya lo cambie a 150,000, aun asi si capturo el precio de 160,000 me lo sigue multiplicando x 1.16 y no por 1.20

Comment: Fijate lo que has puesto. If (150000 < precio). Es decir precio > 150.000, o en palabras precio mayor que 150.000. Si esta condición se cumple entra y usas iva1 "1.16". Deberías poner if (precio < 150000), es decir,precio menor que 150.000.

Comment: gracias @David_helo, con eso a quedado, primero la variable y luego el valor numerico

Answer (score 0):

Además de que el bug es como te dijeron que pusiste el 15000 en el if en lugar de 150000, creo que tu clase Auto sería mucho mejor y más clara así:

```
public class Auto {

  static final float IVA1= 1.16f;
  static final float IVA2= 1.20f;

  private String marca="";
  private String modelo="";
  private String uso="";
  private int año=0;
  private float precio=0;

  public Auto(){
    // Empty constructor
  }

  public Auto(String marca, 
        String modelo,
        String uso,
        int año,
        float precio){
    this.marca=marca;
    this.modelo=modelo;
    this.uso=uso;
    this.año=año;
    this.precio=precio;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    StringBuilder desc = new StringBuilder("Marca:)
      .append(this.marca)
      .append(" ")
      .append("Modelo:") //etc. hasta el precio

    if (this.precio < 150000) {
      desc.append(this.precio * IVA1);
    } else {
      desc.append(this.precio * IVA2);
    }
    return desc;
  }
}
```

Comment: gracias, lo pruebo y comento